# Randomly not loading images in Internet Explorer 10: how to fix?

Tags: image, wordpress, loading, internet-explorer-10

I'm developing a WordPress theme and in IE 10 the images are randomly not showing. All I got is the frame like this:

[image: Frame image not loaded in IE10]

If I reload maybe the image shows off, but another would have the same behaviour.
Looking in IE Dev Tools, in the Network section, this is what I got:

[image: Network tools IE10]

"Terminato" is Italian for "Terminated". It seems like it can't even make the request: there are no response headers nor request headers, nothing.

The strange thing is that if I click on "show image" in the image's context menu, the image will show just fine.

Do someone know how this problem can be solved?

Comment: Is the issue image specific?

Comment: Yes, only images have this problem

Comment: I meant by is there specific images it does this to?

Comment: Ah, sorry: no it's random, it doesn't affect always the same image.

Comment: Personally I had something similar happening to one of our servers.  The only way to fix it was increase the connection limit that was on the server (which helped but we ultimately had to move servers).  Sometimes it has something to do with the cache & JS that was being sent from the server and IE not recognizing/connecting to it.  When you use tools like http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/ do you get the same result where it is unable to download the file?  May want to reset all your IE settings just to give that a shot.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not a problem that occur only on my machine: different people around the world are having this problem, only with IE10

Comment: it seems you are not alone. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-10

Answer (score 1):

Never have seen something similar to this, but here are some suggestions:

**1. Delete browsing history:**
Using CRTL + SHIFT + DEL.

**2. Reset Internet Explorer:**
Open IE > Tools > Internet Options > Advanced > Reset > Check "delete personal settings" > Reset > Restart IE.

**3. Most important: Use Internet Explorer with no add-ons installed:**
Click on the gear icon on the right of your screen, then "Manage add-ons". Then disable all of them and try again.

**4. Upload the files to a online server instead of your localhost.**